How to get username for top posts for a certain keyword using selenium in python
Trying to get to the top posts for a keyword on instagram and capture their username and save it into a csv. Since the username is only displayed when the post is clicked I am unable to find the correct xpath that would make selenium click on that post. Any insights would be helpful!

Instagram has an official API.  There's no need to resort to this kind of delicate hackery to extract information.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

I whould suggest you just follow the link extract the name from there.
E.g.
<a class="bunch of classes" href="/p/abc123/" role="link" tabindex="0"><div class="_aagu"><div class="_aagv"></a>

instead of clicking the link, extract the href and visit https://www.instagram.com/p/abc123/
A better way is to use the api endpoint for the hastag-search by Meta for Instagram.
